# Regex replacement with prompting/callback UI

Tags: javascript, regex, templates, callback

I'm trying to write a function that takes a long string of text, identifies place holders within the text, and prompts the user to supply a value that should take the place of the placeholder. The markup for the placeholders looks similar to markdown used for images or links:

```
some text, some more text, ?[name][description] more text, not just commas
```

Where `name` and `description` are arbitrary runs of text. When I've found these placeholders, I want to pop up a nicely formatted dialog, using the names and descriptions, and have the user supply a replacement value.

I already have a nice function (called `htmlPrompt`) available where you hand it a piece of HTML (for the main part of the prompt), has a text box, and then calls a callback function you've supplied with the result (or `null` if Cancel is pressed), with the following signature:

```
function (htmlText, inputStartValue, callback)
```

Before plugging in this function, I wrote the rough and ready:

```
myText = myText.replace(/(\?\[(.+)\][ ]?(?:\n[ ]*)?\[(.+)\])/g,
   function (wholematch, m1, m2, m3) {
  var repValue = prompt(m2);
  if (repValue == null)
  {
    return m1;
  }
  return repValue;
});
```

Which uses the DOM built-in `prompt` method - which doesn't really do an adequate job for me, when it comes to formatting.

However, I can't think of a way of plugging in `htmlPrompt` - it only *simulates* a modal dialog and provides the final result by calling `callback`.

I did think of trying to manually do the replacements, using the results from `match` rather than `replace` - but so far as I can see, the values returned by `match` are just strings - they don't give you anything useful (such as the location of the match within the overall text).

Or do you think I'm going about this completely wrong? The overall flow I want is:

- Find each placeholder in the text
- Prompt the user for a replacement, using both the `name` and `description` values
- Replace the placeholder expressions in the text with the user supplied value.

Comment: why cant you modify htmlPrompt so that it returns the input instead of calling the callback function?

Comment: @palindrom - because it's based on a model of simulating a modal dialog - by placing an un-editable window-sized `div` behind the `div` that contains the UI for the dialog, then exiting all currently running user javascript and letting the normal browser event loop run - which is fairly standard under javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each of the `name` and `description` tupples:

First use `match` to read `name` and `desription`.
Prompt user.
Then use `replace` to replace those.

Comment: I did something similar to this, but using `search` instead of max, and moving chunks of text from a `before` string to an `after` string so that I didn't have to keep searching text that I new no longer contained the placeholders.